# Help with interpreting this manual using hexadecimal message

Tags: serial, communication

There's a device which I want to control by sending telegram and it has no online manual:

--to be updated the whole manual file here--

The physical layer defined with no parity at the first page. But there is parity defined as "add all data bytes together" which I don't understand.

According to the above manual what telegram turns on the laser and what telegram set the temperature of the laser to 30C?

(I thought these two examples would show me how to interpret it)

Comment: You are confusing the physical layer (basic serial protocol with no parity bit) with the logical protocol which is built *on top* of the physical. The physical protocol settings are the ones you program your UART with. The logical protocol is the "telegram" format, implemented in your software..

Comment: I see thanks for that nice point. However I still cannot proceed I need to see two examples since I am confused about rest of telegram creation I would really appreciate million times if you could help me with two examples I mentioned. im stuck here for some reason :((

Comment: A couple of questions:
1) OP what protocol is that? Is Telegram a protocol on its own?
2) @EugeneSh. Hm so he does not need to send a parity right? But i dont see in the manual anywhere to mention that "this part is the physical layer, the other part is the protocol". 

Did OP post all the useful information about the datasheet? I think we need more from the datasheet, or the datasheet is badly-written.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios 1.1 is listing the UART settings - no parity there. But the telegram format has the 2 parity bytes, that need to be composed based on message. The separation to the layers is natural from these pages.

Comment: @EugeneSh. At the framing section on top "command byte" is given as 1 byte. But on the list command bytes are 2 bytes such as 0xD1 ect. Is that something I interpret wrong here as well?

Comment: @pnatk get yourself an eraser and erase all instances of the term `parity` and insert the term `check digit`

Comment: 0xD1  is one byte.

Comment: @pnatk 0xD1 is one byte ... binary 11010001 (1101=D, 0001=1) ... decimal 209

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample message from Master to Slave to turn the laser ON:

```
0xAA 0x55 0xC1 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00
|_______|  |    |    |  |________| 
 header    |    |   data   parity
        Command |
              Data length
```

Here the command is 0xC1, which must be accompanied with data of length 1, telling ON or OFF. The parity is the data bytes added - which is simply 0x0001 in little endian

Comment: Hmm why must 'data' be 0x01? since we want to only transfer the command for on/off? can 'data; be 0x00?

Comment: Data is 0x00 for OFF and 0x01 for ON. As I said, this is an example to turn it ON.. let me capitalize it in the answer..

Answer (score 1):

After @Eugene Sh. 's transfer, i think mine should be just right to turn the heat to 30oC
**Edit: swapped parity bytes and fixed data format**

[image]

Comment: You are right. I am editing this.

Comment: Is 6B76 same with 0x6B 0x76? (like in parity and header)

Comment: Yes yes, it is the same. Let me edit this as well to make it more clear.

Comment: Note, that between these transmissions you should also get and interpret the response messages from the slave

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes the last section shows what command to send to receive such response data in bytes. I guess I should use bit masking  to extract certain bytes correct?

Comment: @pnatk Bit masking is needed to extract *bits*. If you read it as an array of bytes, you will have bytes

Comment: @EugeneSh. I see so I need to read as array of bits and apply bitmask?

Comment: @pnatk If we are talking C, then you cannot have array of bits. Byte is the smallest addressable unit.